# Is \c_empty_box intended to be used instead of \mbox{}

Tags: boxes, expl3

At a first glance, I understood `\c_empty_box` as a replacement of `\mbox{}` but the following MWE (that points out a weird behavior of `\c_empty_box`: it is replaced by "æ") gives me serious doubts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_foo_tl%
\tl_new:N \l_bar_tl%

\tl_set:Nn \l_foo_tl {%
  \mbox{} \hfill Foo
}
\tl_set:Nn \l_bar_tl {%
  \c_empty_box \hfill Bar
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\baz}{ }
{
  \l_foo_tl
  \par
  \l_bar_tl
}%

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\baz
\end{document}
```

Comment: Side note: shouldn't `\box_use:N` be used?

Comment: I guessed you're right but the David's answer gives me serious doubts (LaTeX3 in general gives me serious doubts ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As with other constant variables, `\c_empty_box` is intended as a fixed data point for use in for example comparisons. It should not be assigned and should be accessed using `\box_use:N` in contexts where a `<box>` is not marked as 'expected'.

The `expl3` language is intended for lower-level programming and so should not be expected to have equivalents of every LaTeX2e document command, and at the same time there are still areas to be developed. The high-level LaTeX2e `\mbox` is a very different construct and is intended for inserting a horizontal box containing the given argument. Internally, `\mbox` uses `\leavevmode`, and this uses `\voidb@x`. The equivalence of `\c_empty_box` and `\voidb@x` may have led to the confusion.

At present, there is still discussion to be had on how best to handle `\leavevmode` functionality. What is almost certain is that it will be implemented using the equivalent of

```
\protected\def\leavevmode{%
  \ifvmode
    \expandafter\indent
  \fi
}
```

rather than an unbox operation. This is because the construct above switches to horizontal mode such that this is complete before `\everypar` is inserted, whereas the 'classical' `\leavevmode` definition leaves the unboxing after the `\everypar` tokens. (pdfTeX and LuaTeX have `\quitvmode` to the same effect as the 'improved' defintion above, but XeTeX lacks this and in any case there is no gain from the additional primitive.)

Answer (score 10):

No, as its name shows it does not take an argument. It is in fact

```
> \c_empty_box=\char"1A.
l.5 \show\c_empty_box

> \box26=void
```

that is it is it is like `\voidb@x` defined by

```
\newbox\voidb@x % permanently void box register
```

in 2e or plain tex.

`\mbox` does `\leavevmode` to start a paragraph and then makes an `\hbox` with no internal content.

like all box allocations, what is actually stored is just the number (that can be passed to `\box`, `\setbox` or `\wd` primitives. Conventionally the allocation routines use `\chardef` tokens to store the numbers. So if you just access the token without prefixing with a box command then you get `\char26` so whatever is in that slot in the current font encoding.

Comment: Hum, sorry: I'm not accustomed to such debugging and to deep 2e or plain tex things (especially concerning boxes). As pointed out by Manuel, is it safe to use `\box_use:N \c_empty_box` instead of `\mbox{}`?

Comment: no `box_use_N` is the primitive `\copy` so that would copy an unallocated box register so just do nothing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think this explains (in a “not so easy and understandable way”, IMO) what happens. But what should be done?

Comment: @Manuel just using `\mbox` is fine (no worse than using `\hfill` in the following token)) so I was concentrating on why what was there didn't work rather than what should be done to fix it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Still, it's not clear to me. May be because I don't understand what are you showing from the .log/terminal. In any case, isn't this related because of the definition of `\leavemode` (something with `\voidb@x`). I don't know, I feel like something is missing from this answer :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I hoped `\c_empty_box` was a general constant for empty boxes that lets us avoid subterfuges as `\mbox{}`. BTW, you suggest `\mbox` + `\hfill` is not ideal; what do you advise instead?

Comment: @Manuel `\leavvmode` is `\unhbox`voidb@x` but that's not really like `\mbox{}` which is `\leavevmode\hbox{}` in particular `\mbox` puts a box into the horizontal list.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé the `\mbox{}\hfill` construct seems to be a version of `\hspace*{\fill}` and to be honest I'd probably use that if you were generating document level markup which isn't really intended to be covered by the expl3 programming layer.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé it is not empty as in `\hbox{}` which is an hbox with no content, it is declared but not set at all, it is not an hbox or a vbox it is just nothing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What would be the `expl3`'s equivalent of `\hspace*{\fill}`?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé probably the same (unless Joseph corrects me) expl3 is really the programming layer below such commands.